# Python Bokeh - Plot not updating when Select is changed

Tags: python, bokeh

I've written a function which basically makes some calculations and returns a Bokeh plot object.

Then I'm calling that function to display some initial output to the user. After that I have a function which is there to check for updates.
I also have a Select, so the user can select option he/she wants. Finally, I'm updating the plot.

Here's the structure of the code:

```
plot = my_custom_function(dataset, 'input_parameter')

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if new == 'some_other':
        plot = my_custom_function(dataset, new)
    else:
        plot = my_custom_function(dataset, old)

select = Select(title='Charging Station', options=['the_first', 'some_other'], value='the_first')
select.on_change('value', update_plot)

layout = row(select, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

The problem is, the chart is not updating? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to mention here:

- First, are you running this with the Bokeh server, i.e. `bokeh serve maypp.py`? Real Python callbacks (e.g. with `on_change`) only work in the Bokeh server (the Bokeh server is the Python process that actually runs the callback code)
- Your callback, as written, has no effect whatsoever. You assign to a *local variable* `plot` that only exists inside the callback function, and then disappears as soon as the function ends. You have not actually updated anything, so the entire callback is a no-op. What the callback needs to do is modify the plot you made earlier, e.g. by updating the existing data sources. A typical Bokeh app has a structure along the lines of:

  ```
  source = ColumnDataSource(...)
  p = figure(...)
  p.line(..., source=source)

  def update(attr, old, new):
      source.data = some_new_data  # Update the *existing* data source
      p.title.text = "new title"   # Update properties on *existing* objects

  select = Select(...)
  select.on_change('value', update)
  ```

  All of the [example apps in repository](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app) follow this kind of pattern.

The last thing to mention is that it is always 100% best practice to make *the smallest change possible*. I.e. you should update the `.data` for an existing data source, not replace entire data sources (or plots) with new ones. Bokeh is optimized for this kind of updating.